# vimscript: How to substitute in current selection?

Tags: vim

Inside a function I can use:

```
s/foo/bar/ge
```

but it only substitutes the current line.
I'd like to substitute in the current selection.  I tried

```
'<,'>s/foo/bar/ge
```

with no success.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you tried, `'<,'>s/foo/bar/ge` should have worked for a selection, even multi-line.  Can you show an example of text that it is not working for?

Comment: `:'<,'>s/foo/bar/ge` works in the command line but inside a function it gives an error. I believe it is a syntax error since single quotes mean string separators.

Comment: Raul, you might want to add, how you plan to call that function. With that information, you might get a answer that exactly matches your usecase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly fine:

```
fun! Foo()
    '<,'>s/foo/bar/ge
endfun
```

You may get `E20: Mark not set` when no visual selection has yet been established, though. For the `'<,'>` marks to be defined, **visual mode must have been left already**; but this is also accomplished by the `:` command that is used to invoke the function, so it shouldn't be a problem (except for special cases like [`:help :map-<expr>`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-%3Cexpr%3E)). If you establish the visual selection only within the function, you need to leave it. Instead of

```
:normal! Vjj
```

append a `<Esc>` to leave visual mode (and set the marks):

```
:execute normal! "Vjj\<Esc>"
```

Note that hard-coding the selection often is bad style; you usually want a mapping to work either on the selection, or `[count]` lines, or the current line / entire buffer. For that, it's advisable to define the function with the `range` attribute; see [`:help function-range-example`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#function-range-example) for details.

Comment: In fact this is the problem (E20: Mark not set) since the selection is being made inside the function. ` fun! Foo() norm Vjj '<,'>s/foo/bar/ge endfun `

Comment: Ah, that would have been valuable information for your question (the reproducible example that StackOverflow asks for). I've extended my answer.